# excel how to replace using wildcard character

Tags: microsoft-excel

in the excel, I have data like

```
Series_post
Series_get
```

I want to find and replace it to

```
<Series_post>
<Series_get>
```

I tried

```
find: Series*
replace: <Series*>
```

But it doesn't really work. It can find the cells, but replace them with `<Series*>` all the time.

Comment: Not with standard functionality. Is vba an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That type of replace is not a standard functionality in Excel but is do able using VBA:

```
Sub wrap_in_tag()

    With ActiveSheet.Cells

        Dim c As Variant, firstAddress As String, sFind As String

        sFind = InputBox("Enter search critera, e.g. Series* will result <Series_test>:" _
        , "Enter Critera")

        If sFind = "" Then Exit Sub

        Set c = .Find(sFind, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                c.Value = "<" & c & ">"
                Set c = .Find(sFind, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. can you edit this script so that all highlighted cells will add <> to them? sorry I am very new to VBA script.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to replace `Se` by `<Se` and also `t` by `t>`.